# Can I join table one more time to existing join?

Tags: sql, database, select, join, relational-database

I have following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
  JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
  JOIN C ON B.id = C.b_id
  JOIN D ON C.id = D.c_id;
```

I need to join another table to it - table E.
But I need to join it on B.id and E.a_id.
Can I write query like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
  JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
  JOIN C ON B.id = C.b_id
  JOIN D ON C.id = D.c_id
  JOIN E ON B.id = E.a_id;
```

Is this correct way of doing this?

Comment: Yes.  The `ON` clause can refer to any of the tables already defined in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - technically not quite true. You can refer to tables which have already been joined. Only generally noticable if you're mucking about with the order of `ON` clauses. E.g. in `select
 *
from
 t1
  inner join
 t2
  inner join
 t3
  on
   t1.id = t3.id
  on
   t2.id = t3.id`, that first `on` clause errors because `t1` isn't in scope yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. If you think that joins just join *tables* together, this is probably what's steering you wrong.

Take a simple example:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   A
     INNER JOIN --J1
   B
     ON A.id = B.a_id
     INNER JOIN  --J2
   C
     ON B.id = C.b_id
```

If we look at the first `JOIN`, `J1`, it's true that this is a join between two tables - `A` and `B`. But in the second `JOIN`, `J2`, the join is between table `C` and *the result of the previous `JOIN`*. At this point, it's valid to reference any of `A`, `B` or `C` in this join's `ON` clause (or none of them, but that's usually an error).

So long as you're not mixing around `ON` clauses (each `JOIN` is immediately followed by its matching `ON` clause), each `JOIN` is always going to be adding a new table (or another instance of an existing table) onto the result of the previous `JOIN` and all tables will be in scope for the `ON` clause.

---

Since I've given it as an example in comments and it's proving a discussion point, let's also have:

```
select
    *
from
    t1
       inner join --J1
    t2
       inner join --J2
    t3
       on t2.id = t3.id --O1
       on t1.id = t3.id --O2
```

What's going on here? Well, `JOIN` and `ON` don't have to appear together, and they actually act a bit like parenthesis. So, the first `JOIN` that happens in this from clause is `J2` - and it's matched to `O1`. *After* that `JOIN`, we then complete join `J1` using `O2`. In this case, `J1` ends up being a join between `t1` and *the result of the join between `t2` and `t3`*.

Because you have to carefully parse this style to work out what order joins are happening in and which `ON` clauses match to which `JOIN`, I'd not normally recommend writing such joins.

Comment: I didn't know that we can write like this: 
`select * from t1 inner join t2 inner join t3 on t1.id = t3.id on t2.id = t3.id`
In which cases we need to put all `ON` clauses after all `JOIN` clauses?

Comment: @Don_Quijote - that's just a variation. I wouldn't normally recommend writing a query like that because it's difficult to read and understand. It was just an illustration of why saying that `ON` clauses can always reference preceding tables was incorrect. So, in short, don't write your joins like that unless you're trying to prove a point :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Some tips for the join querys.

Try to use primary key in the `ON` clause, otherwise create index in this columns and avoid to use `*` choose just the columns that you need. For more information improve your question.